# How to set up a single object instance for an application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, instance

I'm following an MVVM pattern for my application and to prevent memory leaks, I need to cut down the number of object instances to one. This object instance should then be handed of to the other classes where needed.

In my current implementation the instance is being set up in the AppVM, and passed to the `AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel`. But from doing a search for the `MyoDeviceModle()` instance, a second instance is shown here in the `AdductionAbductionFlexionView`.

My question is how can I set up the constructor in the `AdductionAbductionFlexionView` to take the `_connectedDevice` instance that's being used throughout the app?

This is the AppVM showing the main and only instance that should be used:

```
private MyoDeviceModel _connectedDevice;

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationViewModel"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {
            _connectedDevice = new MyoDeviceModel();
            // Add available pages
            PageViewModels.Add(new HomeViewModel(new UserLoginModel()));
            PageViewModels.Add(new AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel(_connectedDevice, new DatabaseModel()));


            // Set starting page
            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];
        }
```

And this is how its passed to the `AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel`:

private MyoDeviceModel _myoDevice;
    private DatabaseModel _dataObj;

```
public event Action<string> DataChanged;

private string _itemString;


/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Myodevice">The device.</param>
/// <param name="progressData">The progress data.</param>
public AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel(MyoDeviceModel Myodevice, DatabaseModel progressData)
{

    DataSubmitCommand = new RelayCommand (this.SaveChangesToPersistence);
    CalibrationSetCommand = new RelayCommand(this.CallibratePitchMinimumCall);
    DatabaseSearchCommand = new RelayCommand(this.QueryDataFromPersistence);

    _myoDevice = Myodevice;
    _myoDevice.MyoDeviceStart();

    _dataObj = progressData;

    _myoDevice.StatusUpdated += (update) =>
    {
        CurrentStatus = update;   
    };


    _myoDevice.PoseUpdated += (update) =>
    {
        PoseStatus = update;   
    };


    _myoDevice.PainfulArcDegreeUpdated += (update) =>
    {
        PainfulArcStatus = update;
    };


    _myoDevice.DegreesUpdated += (update) =>
    {
        DegreeStatus = update;
    };

    _myoDevice.StartDegreeUpdated += (update) =>
    {
        StartDegreeStatus = update;    
    };

    _myoDevice.EndDegreeUpdated += (update) =>
    {
        EndDegreeStatus = update;    
    };


}
```

But I'm wondering how I can pass the `_connectedDevice` instance instead of `new MyoDeviceModel()`

```
        public AdductionAbductionFlexionView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel(new MyoDeviceModel(), new DatabaseModel()); 
            this.Loaded += AdductionAbductionFlexionView_Loaded;
            this.Loaded -= AdductionAbductionFlexionView_Loaded;

            ((AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel)DataContext).DataChanged += x =>
            {

                new ToastPopUp("Submit Succeeded!", "Progress data submitted succesfully", NotificationType.Information)
                {
                    Background = new LinearGradientBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 189, 222), System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 10, 13, 248), 90),
                    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 189, 222)),
                    FontColor = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
                }.Show();

            };

        }
```

Comment: why do you say that is a second instance since you are passing the instance in the constructor of  AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel, it seems to me you are using one instance.

Comment: I forgot to rename, these are two separate instances. I want to remove the  _myoDeviceSecondObj and only reference the instance from the AppVM which is `_myoDevice `

Comment: that is still the same, you code is fine, you are using one instance since you passing it in the constructor of AdductionAbductionFlexionViewModel.  You do not need to change anything.  Unless I am missing something

Comment: It's not clear what doesn't work in your code example. Also, you haven't provided [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the problem. Please read that link, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clearer, useful way.

Comment: @PeterDuniho edited the question for better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the initial instance to the other class's constructor. Thus you do use only one instance and not two. If you don't want to pass the instance around, you need to look at implementing a [Singleton Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: yes got that figured out, I seem to have another instance in my View though, will add that to my question.

Comment: @BrianJ, iro other instances, you need to wrap your instance using the singelton pattern. Then you can access this instance anywhere in your code through the static member that contains the instance and do not need to create other instances. That it is the purpose of a singleton.